# Wordpress URL Redirect and Mask on same Domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mask

I'm frankly very new to .htaccess files and was wondering if someone could help me.

I'm running a Wordpress website and would like to redirect my example.com/index.html page to example.com/somthing/portfolio

I set up a simple 301 redirect but that does not keep example.com in the address bar but switches to example.com/somthing/portfolio

Is there a way to keep the 301 redirect but keep only my domain for that particular link? In other words I'd like the visitor to land on a portfolio page which via Wordpress can not be assigned as default home page (as it is housed under Projects), but essentiality keep my domain name in the address bar.

Current default Wordpress .htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My 301 redirect:

```
Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com/portfolio/portfolio/ports/
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Redirecting a URL**
Using Redirect in an .htaccess file enables you to redirect users from an old page to a new page without having to keep the old page. For example, if you use index.html as your index file and then later rename index.html to home.html, you could set up a redirect to send users from index.html to home.html. For example:

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html http://www.example.com/new/file/new.html
```

The first path to the old file must be a local UNIX path, NOT the full path. So, if the .htaccess file is in the directory /example.com, you would not include /home/exampleuser/example.com in the local UNIX path. The first / represents the example.com directory. If the old file was in that directory, you would follow the / with the old file name.

The second path to the new file can be a local UNIX path, but can also be a full URL to link to a page on a different server or the same server.

```
Redirect /index.html /new/
Redirect /index.html /default.html
Redirect /private/ http://www.example.com/private/
Redirect /img/logo.gif http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif
```

You can check this link for more if you need https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file- 
I Think you may help that article.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware what redirects in a .htaccess file do, and its structure. I'm aware that the old page does not need to exist but in this case I do not want to redirect my entire domain name hence used /index.html 

Is there a better example to create a redirect with URL mask you can provide for Wordpress?